# Spring MVC Controller Instantiation

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I've been told that in a Spring MVC web application, when we have a Spring MVC Controller with its local variables, it is possible that multiple requests may use the same Spring MVC Controller instance.

Let's assume I have this Spring MVC Controller.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/test/me/")
public class TestInstantiation {

    private String myValue;

    @RequestMapping(path = "/try", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String execute(String input, HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse httpResp) throws IOException 
    {
        myValue = input;

        //Let's have a lengtly operation here...

        httpResp.getWriter().write(myValue);
    }
}
```

If multiple clients send a request to `/test/me/try` with different input values, it is possible that one may receive someone's `myValue` value.

I am not sure about this claim. I'd appreciate any guidance on that.

Comment: Keeping state in a singleton (which is whatyour servlet is) should not be done. Referencing another stateless singleton is perfectly fine as that isn't state. Also the `extends HttpServlet` doesn't add anyuthing here actually as you are using a spring controller. Nonetheless sharing state in a singleton instance of any class shouldn't be done due to thread safety.

Comment: @M.Deinum Okay, extending HttpServlet is may bad (copy-paste error here, sorry, I will remove that now). So let's ignore that one. When you say stateless singleton, what do you refer to? Is my servlet a stateless singleton?

Comment: No it is a stateful one because you are keeping state. The `myValue` is state. If you reference another service (say `AccountService`) which doesn't keep state it isn't a problem as soon as something in that chain keeps state you will run into issues.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing two different things:

1. Java's Web Servlet - that is Java EE (today Jakarta EE)'s web-component, that has long been used to develop web applications in Java - namely, a Java object, that can handle (respond to) HTTP messages;

and

2. Spring Framework's `@Controller` component - which is, definitely, under the hood used by Java servlet to handle HTTP messages, but that's not something you should worry about. That was the point of bringing `@Controller`s, to simplify the complexity and boiler-plate of vanilla servlets. You don't create servlet out of controller classes. That means, you don't extend `HttpServlet` abstract class, with your Spring MVC `@Controller` class.

What you were told is probably a point about `Dispatcher Servlet`, which is a Spring Web Framework's implementation for Front-Controller design pattern, that's used in MVC applications.

> *If multiple clients send a request to /test/me/try with different input values, it is possible that one may receive someone's myValue value.*

Every request will be processed in a separate thread - so every client can pass their Request Parameters (query string or payload) and those parameters will be passed into different invocations of your handler method.

Comment: Could you take a look at the `ThreadSafety` section of https://stackoverflow.com/a/3106909/1124047 When @BalusC says that it is not ThreadSafe, does that mean the servlet variable may be shared between two distinct request?

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question correctly, your Controller looks singleton but for member variable `myValue` you might need to use `StringBuffer` (if its allowed) to make it thread safe so that multiple requests can use this member variable without any issue.

Or else, if there is no further use of `myValue` in other methods then I would suggest to make `myValue` as local to function so that any request will have its own copy of `myValue`.

Comment: Would it differ using String or StringBuffer..? Or any primitive type? I am not trying to share `myValue` instance between different servlets. It is the opposite actually. I want to ensure that `myValue` or any other variable within this servlet's scope is unique to the owner of the HTTPRequest this servlet is called for.

Comment: just edited my answer, please have a look, thanks.

Comment: That is exactly what I want to know. So if I keep my variables in the servlet scope, they may be shared among different HttpRequests. Is that right?

Comment: if you mean to say keeping your variables as member variables of Controller class, then yes, they may be shared among different requests.

Comment: `Every request will be processed in a separate thread - so every client can pass their Request Parameters (query string or payload) and those parameters will be passed into different invocations of your handler method.` from @Giorgi Tsiklauri answer.  Does this conflict with your statement? Or I am misunderstanding? This is only for the `execute` method in my example and does not include member variables. Right?

Comment: As Giorgi mentions, you are mixing 2 things, your code has Spring Controller which is by default singleton. Your class member variable `myValue` is keeping state because its getting assigned by incoming requests. If you don't want your incoming request sharing `myValue` then please consider 2 options which I suggested above. thanks.

Comment: He is keeping state, shoehorning said state in a `StringBuffer` is still keeping (and sharing) state.